# Exporting Contact details to Microsoft Exchange 2007 & 2010

Tags: exchangewebservices

What is the best option for getting contact data into Exchange from an external database/file?"

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with .NET, you should use the Exchange Managed API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(EXCHG.80).aspx